Looking for a Vicor power brick substitutes
Vicor has been a curse of mine; I've inherited many devices in various companies that use their Maxi/Micro family bricks. They have improved a lot over time, but the problem is, they are very hard to purchase.
Vicors are unique in that they have analog-pin-adjustable output that is 10-110% of the nominal. I have not seen anything like this in other units.
So, the question is: short of embarking on a design of our own unit (which will obviously be bulkier and more expensive), are there comparable devices on the market?
So far I have no success of trying to find any.
We are using their 400W 5V bricks, and 2V and 3.3V micro bricks.

Shopping questions are off-topic, but I wouldn't agree that it would be more expensive (per unit) to do your own. Maybe amortized cost of designing over your number of units would be more.  It would certainly be hard to compete with Vicor on power density, they are amazing that way.

Well, perhaps if we built a 1,000 of those, yes. But our demand of various Vicors is under a 100 a year. Low quantities do not aid cost reduction.

I feel your pain.  AFAIK there is no drop-in replacement for Vicor bricks.
I've been out of the game for a while, but back then we shifted some new designs from Vicor to Synqor.  Similar power densities with way less drama.
https://www.synqor.com/

Yes, I used SynQor when I was in Telecom, and it was also the sub for Vicor (which at the time decided to burn the inpur capacitor en masse, while powered from good quality Hendry 48V power stand, after a year in service).
But in this application we use it for its ability to trim from 10% to 110%, and the SynQor, or anyone else I know of, do not have the ability.
